# Formatting matrices with vector elements along column headings?

Tags: math-mode, equations, matrices, bordermatrix

Often I've seen the matrix equation *Ax = b* presented as matrix *A* augmented with vector *b*, with the individual elements *x*_*1* ... *x*_*n* written sequentially as headers across the columns; is it possible to visually achieve this sort of formatting in TeX or LaTeX?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Check out `kbordermatrix` - the `bordermatrix` tag should help.

Answer (score 1):

One option using [`blkarray`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blkarray):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
x_{1} & x_{2} & \cdots & x_{n} \\
  \begin{block}{[cccc|c]}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} & b_{1} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} & b_{2} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn} & b_{m} \\
  \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```